# adb finds only one of two GoogleGlasses

Tags: android, adb, google-glass

this might sound weird:

I have two google glasses. I want to clone one of the glasses to the other one using adb.

But even though both devices have debuggin enabled I can only find one of them in the adb device list.

In my Systems device manager I have *"Android Composite ADB Interface" (the Glass that works with adb)* and *"Android ADB Interface" (the other one)*.

I can only see the former as a Camera in windows explorer. The other one does not show up.

I should have the driver installed then, right?
How do I resolve this issue?

**Update:**

Tried this: http://glassappz.com/ten-easy-steps-to-side-load-an-app-to-google-glass/ (didn't help)

Comment: Does this happen only when both of them are plugged in simultaneously?  What if you plug in one-by-one?  Please clarity.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why how this happened, or why this now works,

but on order to resolve this issue I had to uninstall all drivers associated with the device, disconnect it, reconnect it, run the driver automatic installation by Windows Update and then install the GoogleUSB Driver manually.